# Simple Restful framework/client on iOS other than Restkit?

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, restkit

I have been playing around with Restkit for about a day now and its complexity is driving me insane.

I am looking for a simple, well maintained, restful client on iOS that can communicate with my web server written in rails. I only require the following: Easy call to CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE with flexibility to check the response code as well as the response body (I rely on the response body to set certain server related ids to my objects)

Unfortunately Resty doesn't' really support ARC so it's out of my realms right now.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You can't mark the Resty-files as not using ARC? That way your project could be ARC and you'd still be able to use Resty.

Comment: Actually RestKit is a bit hard at first but you should give it a try. When you understand it, it is really awesome and powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). It's small, fast, well maintained and easy to use.

In addition to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) there is also another lib that has been recently released called [NSRails](https://github.com/dingbat/nsrails), which aims particularly to simplifying CRUD when using Rails. It is a newer lib though and personally I haven't used it, but it looks promising.

Comment: @disappearedng Late to the game here, but I just built a framework for exactly this purpose. It's called [RestMachine](https://github.com/camclendenin/rest-machine) and it's built on top of great AFNetworking but makes it far more convenient to handle CRUD calls throughout your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSURLSession` and `NSJSONSerialization` to retrieve and parse your JSON, then use Github's [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) framework for mapping that JSON to your ObjC classes. Mantle is far more straightforward than RestKit.